# Cell-phones and protocol-stack

Tags: tcp, voip, telephony

When making a phone-call these day - the datastream is divided into packages, isnt it? But which protocol-stack is used then? VOIP is using tcp-ip but but what about cell-phones? For instance - the header of a package in a certain layer should use the phonenumber to route the package to the right destination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Assuming North America as our venue) The voice part of a mobile connection, like non-mobile ISDN voice network, has been circuit switched up until LTE. LTE is only packet switched, so either Voice over LTE is used (sort of like VoIP) or voice is sent circuit switched separately from the packet switched data. It turns out that right now, that for most networks, the phone falls back to 2G/3G service when there is a voice call in progress, due to the difficulties in rolling out VoLTE.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_(telecommunication)

It looks like voice traffic is modeled in three layers: Physical, Media Access Control, and the "call-processing state machine" (which seems to be more like a layer 7 application than anything else from the OSI model). Layer 3 turns analog audio from the microphone into a digital stream, Layer 2 creates frames that combine the voice data with internet data and signaling. And layer 1, which carries the layer 2 frames of course, is where the fancy radio frequency modulation goes on.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IS-95

If you want to be blown away by what are essentially mathematical tricks used more and more in signaling over the last 20 - 30 years, delve into layer 1 for both mobile communications and high-speed internet starting with DSL. QPSK and QAM alone are really fascinating.